# Android US States Data Provider

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, iso

I have a very common use case.  The user needs to enter their address (if they choose not to use reverse geo-location).

For the state portion of this, I want them to be able to select their state from a list.  With Android, it seems as if it would be easy to have a content provider which provides the functionality for this common use case to all applications.  Is there such a thing pre-built?  Or am I going to have to create my own content provider?  I know ISO maintains a nice list of countries and their states (Authority and Subauthoriy I believe?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say which country you're interested in, or if the country can change within your app.

If you're talking about the United States, I'd say that you can get away with a hard-coded [list of states](http://www.50states.com/).  We aren't planning to annex any new ones, and the chances of somebody seceding from the Union are small in this 150th anniversary year of the start of the Civil War.

Comment: I'm currently interested in the US only.  However, it seems like a content provider of countries and their state/provinces would be pretty common.  However I notice apps such as the contact manager just have you type in the state info...

Comment: -1 this is not a sustainable solution. For apps that have long lifetimes (i.e. ones made on Android-based non-personal devices), we're going to want a more long-term, reliable, official solution.

Comment: Nonsense. OP accepted it. Let's talk if TX secedes.

Comment: This might be obvious, but could provide a drop-down, but also allow people to put in their own text in the "state" field. Puerto Rico just voted to become an official US State. However for address purposes, they were already a state and would have been included along with American Samoa and stuff.

Comment: By all means expose a service that provides the current list as a JSON service.  Nice and RESTful.